# Would this question be off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm planning on building a 4 wheeled ATV.  I'm going to buy a frame.  It will be about the size of a small [Razor](http://www.louisianasportsman.com/classifieds/pics/p1357782871483427.jpg), if your familiar with those.

I want to build the question around the rear end.  It can be viewed as subjective but I think if I ask the question properly it won't be.

My question would sound something like this.

> the driving conditions I'm building it for would include slow rocky terrain in the desert with high heat conditions.  It would do a lot of time on hard pack dirt roads getting to locations.  I'm concerned if a go with a solid axle rear end like an Yamaha Raptor that the rear end will slide to much getting out of turns on the hard pack so I'm considering shaft drive with type of diff and incorporated into a swing arm setup.  No independent.  Based upon the information provided is there a correct choice?

As I'm writing the draft question I feel like I'm giving myself the answer of NO.  This is not the kind of question for SE.

Any input or guidance is appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: If there is a trade-off that you want to discuss it would be better in my opinion. Maintainability, cost, safety...